# Memory safety of “+=” operator in Swift

Tags: swift, inout, memory-safety

I’ve been learning swift and encountered a question about memory safety. The `+=` operator takes an `inout` parameter on the left, which should have write access over the entire function call. And it do something like `left = right+left` within its implementation. It seems to be an overlapping of write and read accesses. How comes this doesn’t violate memory safety?

Edit:
According to [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/MemorySafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH46-ID567), it can happen in a single thread:

> However, the conflicting access discussed here can happen on a single thread and doesn’t involve concurrent or multi-threaded code.

Elaborate: 
Here are two examples from *The Swift Programming Language (Swift 4.1 beta).* I’m confused how this custom `+=` implementation in a struct `Vector2D` is okay:

```
static func += (left: inout Vector2D, right: Vector2D) {
    left = left + right
}
```

When this is not:

```
var stepSize = 1
func incrementInPlace(_ number: inout Int) {
    number += stepSize
}
incrementInPlace(&stepSize)
// Error: conflicting accesses to stepSize
```

Further edit:

I think my problem really is that += as a func, specifically when used

```
stepSize += stepSize
```

Or with custom implementation:

```
var vector = Vector2D(x: 3.0, y: 1.0)
vector += vector
```

This doesn’t have any error. But the func takes an inout from the left and thus have a long-term write access to “step”, then if the right also passed in “step”, I’m confused how that isn’t an instant read acess of “step” overlapping with long term write of “step.” Or is it only a problem when you pass in the same instance for two inout parameters, but nor one inout and one regular?

Comment: Can you elaborate your point? Of course it does not violate memory safety. Why does having a read and write access on the same line break memory safety?

Comment: I’ve added elaboration to the post and exert from the book The Swift Programming Language (Swift 4.1 beta) If you can take a look?

Comment: In your first example, `left` is being incremented by some value, which is fine. In your second example, `number` (which is an `inout` reference to `stepSize`), is being incremented by itself, `stepSize`. The unsafe nature of the second example does not arise from the `+=`, but rather that you're changing the `inout` left hand side using the same memory in the right hand side expression.

Comment: Now I see, I was too focused on the “inout” that I thought it created a problem with “+=“  that doesn’t actually exist. Then I realize it is in the end a problem with any one-line code changing self by reading self first

Comment: It's a bit of a vague question, but I think it's a good one. Clearly OP is confused on the topic, and misdiagnosed the source of the issue. However, they provide enough context for us to be able to figure out what they're getting at, so that we can prescribe a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you've got it, but a clarification for future readers; in your comments, you said:

> ... it is, in the end, a problem with any one-line code changing self by reading self first.

No, that alone is not sufficient. As the [Memory Safety](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/MemorySafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH46-ID567) chapter says, this problem manifests itself only when:

> - At least one is a write access.
> - They access the same location in memory.
> - Their durations overlap.

Consider:

```
var foo = 41
foo = foo + 1
```

The `foo = foo + 1` is not a problem (nor would `foo += 1`; nor would `foo += foo`) because constitutes a series of "instantaneous" accesses. So although we have (to use your phrase) "code changing self by reading self first", it is not a problem because their durations do not overlap.

The problem only manifests itself when you're dealing with "long-term" accesses. As that [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/MemorySafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH46-ID567) goes on to say:

> A function has long-term write access to all of its in-out parameters. The write access for an in-out parameter starts after all of the non-in-out parameters have been evaluated and lasts for the entire duration of that function call. If there are multiple in-out parameters, the write accesses start in the same order as the parameters appear.
>
> One consequence of this long-term write access is that you can’t access the original variable that was passed as in-out, even if scoping rules and access control would otherwise permit it—any access to the original creates a conflict.

So, consider your second example:

```
var stepSize = 1
func incrementInPlace(_ number: inout Int) {
    number += stepSize
}
incrementInPlace(&stepSize)
```

In this case, you have a long-term access to whatever `number` references. When you invoke it with `&stepSize`, that means you have a long-term access to the memory associated with `stepSize` and thus `number += stepSize` means that you're trying to access `stepSize` while you already have a long-term access to it.

Comment: I think my problem is that += as a func, specifically “step+=step”. It takes in an inout from the left and thus have a long-term write access to that value “step”, then if the right passed in the same value, I’m confused how that isn’t an instant read of “step” overlapping with long term write of “step”

Comment: @AntoniaZhang The `right` argument is "read instantaneously" and a copy of its value is passed to the `+=` function call, prior to to the start of the `+=` function call (which marks the beginning of the "long-term write access"). Thus, there is no overlap

Comment: "then if the right passed in the same value" ... whoa, there. The question isn't whether the parameter on the right is the same value or not. The question is whether it's the same _memory address._ But the right parameter value types, so `right` is a copy of the original value, not pointing to the same memory address. Whereas in your question's `stepSize` example, the function is referencing a property called `stepSize` (with a particular memory address) and the `inout` parameter was passed `&stepSize` as `number`, so you're dealing with the same address. Ergo non-safe memory access.

Comment: Here’s how I understand it now: because it is a value type that is being passed on the right, a copy was made when the parameter was evaluated before func call, and thus the instantaneous access happens before the long term access starts. So no overlap! Thank you Alexander and Rob, for finally clearing it all up for me!

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
x +=5
```

which is Equal to

x = x + 5

first a read operation happens to the variable x then the value is  being added to 5 finally a write operation of the result , all of this happens synchronously by registers it's not at the same time

Comment: Thanks, but sorry I still don’t get it, shouldn’t the func += be taking an inout parameter from the left hand side? And shouldn’t the functions have long-term write access to their inout parameters, from start to end of the func? And the read access only happened within the func’s declaration right? How comes the read access can happen after the write access end?

Comment: This a high level line of code what actually happens is that line converted to a set of assembly lines that you might see during a crash , with a single thread no conflict can happen because it's guarantee that at a time a single instruction is being executed so read and write can't happen at the same time to the variable

Comment: Could you explain more? Also I added elaboration in the post if you can take a look?